# How to specify type of argument passed to translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I am writing a multilingual website in rails 5. I am writing the translations in some yml files and it works all like a charm. But I was wondering, is there an option to convert an argument I pass to a translation?

I'll explain myself better:

I have this translation:

```
quantity: "%{quantity}g"
```

and I can call it on controllers or views with `I18n.t(:quantity, {quantity: 1.23})` (1.23 is dynamic, I put there for example).

Now, I get `1.23g`, but is there a way to print instead `1g` (I don't know, converting to int, trouncing or rounding) using yml syntax without touching the call or create an helper?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ERB in the yml files:

```rb
quantity: "%{<%= quantity.to_i %>}g"
```

Anyway, maybe is a better idea to use a helper since it's a presentation issue, extracting logic from the locale files.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. However I will follow your suggestion and use an helper instead of writing "real code" in the translations. I hoped for something more like the python pyformat syntax

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't test it. +1 for using a helper ;-)